# Maven JAXB setup for shared xsd file

Tags: java, maven, binding, jaxb

I have a problem with the generated java code of my xsd structures. I am not quite sure how to organize that with maven, so maybe somebody can give me some advice.

I have a common.xsd with some complex types included.

Then I have 
projectA.xsd where I import the common.xsd
projectB.xsd where I import the common.xsd

This is the header of my common.xsd

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns1="de.cargosoft.edi.common" targetNamespace="de.cargosoft.edi.common" elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

Then I have this defined in my projects xsds

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:common="de.cargosoft.edi.common" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:import namespace="de.cargosoft.edi.common" schemaLocation="http://files.cargosoft.de/xsd/CargoSoftCommon/CargoSoftCommon_7.1.2.xsd"/>
```

This is working fine.

Now sometimes the common.xsd will be extended. So I thought about putting the common.xsd into one maven project and only generate the code for those elements under the package **de.cargosoft.xsd.common**

For each other project I used to create a single maven project under the package **de.carosoft.xsd.projectA** or **de.cargosoft.xsd.projectB**
I am not quite sure if that is the best idea to split the xsds into several maven projects or put them all together into one project and use profiles or something like that. Anyway.

How do I tell maven / jaxb to use the **de.cargosoft.xsd.common...** classes when an element with the namespace **common** appears in the project xsds?

I tried it with **xjc** and there it worked with those two calls:

```
xjc -d out -episode common.episode CargoSoftCommon_7.1.2.xsd
xjc -d out CargoSoftWMS_1.0.20.xsd -extension -b common.episode
```

I am using this plugin in the moment:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>src/jaxb/resources/schema</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaFiles>CargoSoftWMS_1.0.20.xsd</schemaFiles>
                <outputDirectory>src/jaxb/java</outputDirectory>
                <packageName>de.cargosoft.csedi.jaxb.wms</packageName>
                <bindingDirectory>src/jaxb/resources/schema</bindingDirectory>
                <bindingFiles>bindung.jxb</bindingFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But how does the binding need to look like? In case of xjc the application created this binding information for me. Can I tell maven to create that as well? But if so, I would have to copy the binding file to each project as soon as the common.xsd will change? Therefor it should be better to create one global maven project with the common.xsd and both project xsds?

Thanks for hints, tips and examples :-)

Many greetings,
Hauke

### -

-

***----- UPDATE 16-12-2013 -------***

I just used a different plugin and now it works. I do have to put all xsds into one project or copy the generated binding file to the other projects in order to work. Here is the plugin tag which worked for me :

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>schema1-generate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/jaxb/resources/schema</schemaDirectory>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <include>CargoSoftCommon_7.1.2.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                        <generatePackage>de.cargosoft.common</generatePackage>
                        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc1</generateDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>schema2-generate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <bindingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc/META-INF</bindingDirectory>
                        <bindingIncludes>
                            <include>sun-jaxb.episode</include>
                        </bindingIncludes>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/jaxb/resources/schema</schemaDirectory>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <include>CargoSoftWMS_1.0.20.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                        <generatePackage>de.cargosoft.wms</generatePackage>
                        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc2</generateDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```